# How to read Data from XML and display in to ListView?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to XML i want to read data from XML i have the following format of XML file.

```
<country>
<coordinates>
    <x-y>
        <x>150</x>
        <y>160</y>
        <cities>
            <city>Mumbai</city>
            <photos>
                <image>
                    <url>Mumbai 1</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 1</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 1</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Mumbai 2</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 2</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 2</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Mumbai 3</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 3</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 3</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Mumbai 4</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 4</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 4</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
            </photos>
        </cities>
    </x-y>
    <x-y>
        <x>155</x>
        <y>165</y>
        <cities>
            <city>Delhi</city>
            <photos>
                <image>
                    <url>Delhi 1</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 1</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 1</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Delhi 2</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 2</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 2</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Delhi 3</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 3</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 3</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Delhi 4</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 4</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 4</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
            </photos>
        </cities>
    </x-y>
    <x-y>
        <x>160</x>
        <y>175</y>
        <cities>
            <city>Jammu</city>
            <photos>
                <image>
                    <url>Jammu 1</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 1</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 1</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Jammu 2</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 2</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 2</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>
                <image>
                    <url>Jammu 3</url>
                    <description>
                        <english>this 3</english>
                        <arabic>this arabic 3</arabic>
                    </description>
                </image>

            </photos>
        </cities>
    </x-y>
</coordinates>
```

I am able to read city name using following code :

```
    public static Boolean getCityList(InputStream inputstream) {
    try {
        Log.e("getCityList", "Comming");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = db.parse(new InputSource(inputstream));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("cities");

        if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
            Cities.initilize();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("city");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                Log.e("City Name : ", ""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());
                Cities cities = new Cities(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());
                Cities.sCityList.add(cities);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The above code read city from the list.
now i want to read url from image and also its description in this function only.
Please help me out.

Comment: i don't understand your issue. if you have the city, obtaining the url shouldn't be very different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now you have to choose the `<image>` as parent node because `<url>` is a child of `<image>` tag. like this

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

    if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
        Cities.initilize();
            Node node = nodeList.item(0);
            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("url");
            // Store it in your city's arraylist

        }
```

hope this helps

Comment: okay for this i have to create a new function that i dont want i want to find all the nodes in one function like store city in cityarray and that city contain images so that all images are store in imagearray and that particular image have description so store that description in description array all this task done in one function. so please help me to make that function.

Comment: thank you @Qadir Hussair this function help me in my case i changed little and got the solution..

Comment: i m glad to hear that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to use [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), it is a lightwight parsing library for android, which will allow you to parse the XML-data pretty easily.